# Latency to cause the scrollto after checkpointing

Tags: jquery, scrollto, latency, qtip2

I created a script (which is not very clean I grant you but it works), but when all my conditions are true, the scroll `$('body,html').scrollTo( $(".ChoixA"),1000);` starts after a few seconds without me explaining it.

```
function Check_Index_Demelant() {
    var choixA = $('#ChoixA').val().toUpperCase();
    var choixA_l = choixA.length;
    var choixB = $('#ChoixB').val().toUpperCase();
    var choixB_l = choixB.length;
    var bulle_index_1 = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('bulle_index_1')); ?>;
    var bulle_index_2 = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('bulle_index_2')); ?>;
    var bulle_index_3 = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('bulle_index_3')); ?>;
    var bulle_index_4 = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('bulle_index_4')); ?>;

// Rien dans les 2
    if(choixA_l == 0 & choixB_l == 0){      
        $('body,html').scrollTo( $(".Index"),1000);
        $('#ChoixA').focus();
        var bulle_index_1 = $('#imagechoix').qtip({
            content: {text: bulle_index_1},
            style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},
            position: {my: 'left center',at: 'center right',adjust: {x: -55,y: -50}},
            show: 'none',hide: 'none'
        });
        var api_bulle_index_1 = bulle_index_1.qtip('api');
        api_bulle_index_1.show();
    }else if (choixA.indexOf('NE PAS') !== -1 || choixA.indexOf('OU PAS') !== -1){
        $('body,html').scrollTo( $(".Index"),1000);
        $('#ChoixA').select(); 
        var bulle_index_1 = $('#imagechoix').qtip({
            content: {text: bulle_index_4},
            style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},
            position: {my: 'right center',at: 'center left',adjust: {x: 55,y: -50}},
            show: 'none',hide: 'none'
        });
        var api_bulle_index_1 = bulle_index_1.qtip('api');
        api_bulle_index_1.show();
    }else if (choixB.indexOf('NE PAS') !== -1 || choixB.indexOf('OU PAS') !== -1){
        $('body,html').scrollTo( $(".Index"),1000);
        $('#ChoixB').select();
        var bulle_index_1 = $('#imagechoix').qtip({
            content: {text: bulle_index_4},
            style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},
            position: {my: 'left center',at: 'center right',adjust: {x: -55,y: -50}},
            show: 'none',hide: 'none'
        });
        var api_bulle_index_1 = bulle_index_1.qtip('api');
        api_bulle_index_1.show();  
    }else if(choixA_l == 0 & choixB_l > 0){
        $('body,html').scrollTo( $(".Index"),1000); 
        $('#ChoixA').focus();   
        var bulle_index_1 = $('#imagechoix').qtip({
            content: {text: bulle_index_2},
            style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},
            position: {my: 'left center',at: 'center right',adjust: {x: -55,y: -50}},
            show: 'none',hide: 'none'
        });
        var api_bulle_index_1 = bulle_index_1.qtip('api');
        api_bulle_index_1.show();      
    }else if(choixA_l > 0 & choixB_l == 0){
        $('body,html').scrollTo( $(".Index"),1000); 
        $('#ChoixB').focus();   
        var bulle_index_1 = $('#imagechoix').qtip({
            content: {text: bulle_index_2},
            style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},
            position: {my: 'left center',at: 'center right',adjust: {x: -55,y: -50}},
            show: 'none',hide: 'none'
        });
        var api_bulle_index_1 = bulle_index_1.qtip('api');
        api_bulle_index_1.show();   
    }else if(choixA ==  choixB ){
        $('body,html').scrollTo( $(".Index"),1000);
        $('#ChoixA').focus();       
        var bulle_index_1 = $('#imagechoix').qtip({
            content: {text: bulle_index_3},
            style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},
            position: {my: 'left center',at: 'center right', adjust: {x: -55, y:-50}},
            show: 'none', hide: 'none'
        }); 
        var api_bulle_index_1 = bulle_index_1.qtip('api');
        api_bulle_index_1.show();   
    }else if(choixA !=  choixB ){   
        var bulle_index_1 = $('#imagechoix').qtip({}); 
        var api_bulle_index_1 = bulle_index_1.qtip('api');
        api_bulle_index_1.hide();  
            $('body,html').scrollTo( $(".ChoixA"),1000);
            print_help_A_0();
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem and/or the intended behaviour is.

Comment: This script acts as an auditor, he looks if the `input` type text are filled correctly and if it shows a tip to guide the user smoothly. In short, once the user has successfully completed the text input type, then the `scroll` window to another page. Except in my case, the window `scroll` late with a few seconds during which it nothing happens. Then `scroll` the window as desired, but the latency is annoying.